# Почему переменная не изменяется во вложенном цикле?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel4

В массиве $books 3 элемента

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
//если вывести здесь       {{$book->id}} результат равен 1,2,3
 @foreach($shops as shop)
  {{$book->id}}
//если вывести здесь       {{$book->id}} результат равен 1,1,1
 @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Почему так происходит и как вывести все id во вложенном цикле?

Comment: Интерпритатор заходит в первый цикл, для первого элемента в массиве/объекте id равен 1. Далее, заходит во второй цикл, и пока он не пройдется по всем элементам он не выйдет из него. Поэтому у вас выводится трижды 1.

Comment: покажите какой у вас массив и что где лежит

Comment: `$books = array(array('id' => '1', 'price' => 123), array('id' => '2', 'price' => 444), array('id' => '3', 'price' => 900));

$shops = array(array('name' => 'shop1'), array('name' => 'shop2'));`